# Disable swiping after first swipe, then reset once done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have the following code which allows me to swipe an element, and the element will move, revealing the element underneath. I'd like to be able to swipe once, have the function run, have the div reset it's position, and allow me to swipe once again. Basically, disable the swiping while the function is running, then enable it once the function is over.

Here's my code:

```
var threshold = {
    x: 30,
    y: 10
}
var originalCoord = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}
var finalCoord = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}

    function touchMove(event) {
        finalCoord.x = event.targetTouches[0].pageX
        changeX = originalCoord.x - finalCoord.x
        var changeY = originalCoord.y - finalCoord.y
        if (changeY < threshold.y && changeY > (threshold.y * -1)) {
            changeX = originalCoord.x - finalCoord.x
            if (changeX > threshold.x) {
                // My function which runs when you swipe left
            }
        }
    }

    function touchEnd(event) {
    }

    function touchStart(event) {
        originalCoord.x = event.targetTouches[0].pageX
        finalCoord.x = originalCoord.x
    }

window.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart, false);
window.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMove, false);
window.addEventListener("touchend", touchEnd, false);
```

I figured I could use `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` to disable dragging once the function runs, but it still ends up allowing me to drag during it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by removing then adding back in the `EventListener`:

```
if (changeX > threshold.x) {
    window.removeEventListener('touchmove', touchMove, false);
    // Function
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove, false);
    }, 800)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty hard to figure out what do you want, but to disable the swiping just add helper variable:

```
var _swipeDisabled = false;
```

then in touchmove check if swiping is disabled, and if so just `return false`:

```
function touchMove(event) {
    if (_swipeDisabled) return false; // this line is crucial
    finalCoord.x = event.targetTouches[0].pageX
    changeX = originalCoord.x - finalCoord.x
    var changeY = originalCoord.y - finalCoord.y
    if (changeY < threshold.y && changeY > (threshold.y * -1)) {
        changeX = originalCoord.x - finalCoord.x
        if (changeX > threshold.x) {
            _swipeDisabled = true; // add this before calling your function
            // My function which runs when you swipe left
        }
    }
}
```

And in your function you'll have to enable the swiping again, so just do:

```
_swipeDisabled = false;
```

in the function you call there. Simpliest solutions are usually the best, remember!

Comment: I thought I made it clear what I was trying to do, what's hard to understand?

Comment: @Charlie The part about resetting the div - I thought that you also want us to write the code to reset the div's position. After reading last sentence before the code in description everything was clear.